# maven profile activation based on existence of several files

Tags: maven

I would like to activate a profile based on the existence of several files. In the following example I want the profile to be activated if both files `my.marker` and `another.marker` exists.

```
    <activation>
        <file>
            <exists>${basedir}/my.marker</exists>
            <exists>${basedir}/another.marker</exists>
        </file>
    </activation>
```

It does not work since it's not valid against the schema. Is there a way to do such a thing without using command line properties?

Answer (score 7):

Actually even with MNG-4565 being solved in Maven 3.2.2 it is still not possible to check for the existence of several files. That is because the POM model doesn't allow multiple `file` nor multiple `exists` elements (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5909). Even mixing `exists` and `missing` in one `file` element does not work (because if the `exists` element is there, it will be considered only and the sibling `missing` element will be disregarded, https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5910)

Answer (score 0):

<del>Unfortunately you can't do this for now. There is a [ticket](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-4565) that could solve your case by using multiple activation conditions, but it is still unresolved.</del>

EDIT: There was an issue with Maven, so you could not do that. However now, starting with 3.2.2 version, it should work by using multiple activation conditions.

Thanks to [Nicholas Daley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/528246/nicholas-daley) for pointing this out.

Comment: Looks like it is fixed in Maven v3.2.2

Answer (score -1):

While not a solution to your problem you could ensure that a profile is run successfully only if two files exist by using [maven enforcer plugin](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireFilesExist.html).

For instance, the snippet below will fail for any maven goal  run with profile `requiresTwoFiles` (e.g. `mvn -P requiresTwoFiles compile`) unless both `src/main/java` and `src/test/java` exist.

```
...
<profile>
    <id>requiresTwoFiles</id>           
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
                <executions>
                      <execution>
                        <id>enforce-files-exist</id>
                        <goals>
                          <goal>enforce</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                          <rules>
                            <requireFilesExist>
                              <files>
                                  <file>${basedir}/src/main/java</file>
                                  <file>${basedir}/src/test/java</file>
                              </files>
                            </requireFilesExist>
                          </rules>                              
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
...
```