# Is it possible to activate maven profile with multiple file exists checks?

Tags: maven, maven-3

My final goal is to build only modules that exist on the file system. As far as I understand, the only way to do it is using profiles.
So, I need to activate maven profile if several files simultaneously exist on the file system:

```
    <profile>
        <id>profile1</id>
        <activation>
            <file>
                <exists>path/to/module1/pom.xml</exists>
                <exists>path/to/module2/pom.xml</exists>
            </file>
        </activation>
        <modules>
            <module>path/to/module1</module>
            <module>path/to/module2</module>
        </modules>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>profile2</id>
        <activation>
            <file>
                <exists>path/to/module1/pom.xml</exists>
                <missing>path/to/module2/pom.xml</missing>
            </file>
        </activation>
        <modules>
            <module>path/to/module1</module>
        </modules>
    </profile>
```

But maven returns an error "Non-parseable POM [my_project]\pom.xml: Duplicated tag: 'exists' (position: START_TAG seen ...\r\n". Trying to use several  checks also returns the "duplicated" error.
Is it possible to use several  checks in one activation block? 
My maven version is 3.2.2.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [maven profile activation based on existence of several files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11134636/maven-profile-activation-based-on-existence-of-several-files)